# Pattern combination

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have patterns: a, abb, a*b+. And I need to combine them to use in a one match operation and to have information of which the pattern correspond to the input string. Can I do this by means of JDK libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about regexes.

Just use `or`s:

```
(a)|(abb)|(a*b+)
```

You can tell which pattern was matched from the index of the group that matched.

Comment: i think he wants to know which of the ors it matches

Comment: I think the OP is referring to [the `Pattern` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Then put each one in a capturing group and see which group got matched.

Comment: If I have a "a" string, I receive group(1)="a", group(2)="a", group(3)="a", don't I?

Comment: True; how do you want to handle that? I would recommend putting the simplest pattern first.

Comment: There is a way to know exactly what is it the pattern? For example, if I program the Deterministic finite Automata, I will know exactly what it is a pattern. But I don`t want to waste time for this routine.

Comment: Huh? I don't know what you mean.  The string `a` should only match group one.

Comment: But if I do something like this (a)|(ab*)|(a*b*) and I hava a "a" string. It returns me  group(1)="a", group(2)="a", group(3)="a" It is very bad.

Comment: @itun: That's not very bad; that's exactly what you asked for.